# How do you set tooltip labels for multiple series using Apache Echarts?

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I'm trying to generate a line chart that uses date for the x-axis and two different y-axis. I have it mostly working, but I can't get the tooltip to display the label properly for the second line.

To see this, go to the [ECharts Demo Editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple) and enter the following code:

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'time'
    },
    yAxis: [
        {
            type: 'value'
        },
        {
            type: 'value'
        }
    ],
    dataset: {
        source: [
            { date: '2020-01-24', orders: 4, sales: 250 },
            { date: '2020-01-25', orders: 3, sales: 250 },
            { date: '2020-01-26', orders: 2, sales: 375 },
            { date: '2020-01-27', orders: 2, sales: 380 },
            { date: '2020-01-28', orders: 4, sales: 325 },
            { date: '2020-01-29', orders: 5, sales: 375 },
            { date: '2020-01-30', orders: 6, sales: 500 },
            { date: '2020-01-31', orders: 4, sales: 425 },
            { date: '2020-02-01', orders: 2, sales: 280 },
            { date: '2020-02-03', orders: 3, sales: 580 },
            { date: '2020-02-04', orders: 4, sales: 250 },
            { date: '2020-02-05', orders: 4, sales: 350 }
        ]
    },
    series: [
        { 
            type: 'line',
            yAxisIndex: 0, 
            dimensions: [
                {
                    type: 'time',
                    name: 'date',
                    displayName: ''
                },
                {
                    type: 'float',
                    name: 'orders',
                    displayName: 'Orders'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            type: 'line', 
            yAxisIndex: 1, 
            dimensions:[
                {
                    type: 'time',
                    name: 'date',
                    displayName: ''
                },
                {
                    type: 'int',
                    name: 'sales',
                    displayName: 'Sales'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis'
    }
};
```

As you can see, the lines render correctly, as do both y axes, but the label for the second series (green line) is empty rather than *Sales*. However, if I delete the first series from the array, *Sales* becomes the blue line and the label works correctly in the tooltip, so there seems to be something I'm missing when using multiple series.

I suspect the fix for this is quite simple and obvious, but I've spent a fair amount of time on it and haven't had any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `name` to series instead of `displayName` to dimension.

```
series: [
    { 
        type: 'line',
        yAxisIndex: 0,
        name:'Orders', // Here
        dimensions: [
            {
                type: 'time',
                name: 'date'
            },
            {
                type: 'float',
                name: 'orders'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: 'line', 
        yAxisIndex: 1, 
        name:'Sales', // Here
        dimensions:[
            {
                type: 'time',
                name: 'date'
            },
            {
                type: 'int',
                name: 'sales'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```